# Query posts outputs news items 5 times

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I have a problem retreiving posts into a page. I try to get posts of a specific category but when the posts get loaded they get displayed 5 times. I allready tried to change the number of posts to view in the admin panel but this doesn't have effect on the output of the posts.

This is my code:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php

        query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'nieuwsitem', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) );

         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php $myposts = get_posts('');
              foreach($myposts as $post) :
              setup_postdata($post);
              ?>
                <div class="post-item">
                  <div class="thedate"><?php echo get_the_time('d/m/Y', $post->ID); ?></p></div>
                  <div class="post-info">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="post-content">
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using a single `WP_Query` for this, not `query_posts` and `get_posts`.  `get_posts` does not require use of the Loop.  Here you are modifying the default query, looping through those posts (`while`), and inside each loop running ANOTHER `foreach` loop that outputs each post which is why you are getting this behavior.  Just use a fresh `WP_Query` and a simple, normal WordPress loop to do this instead.

Comment: See my answer for an implementation with `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created 2 loops. Removing the foreach part of your code should fix this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php

    query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'nieuwsitem', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) );

     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post-item">
              <div class="thedate"><?php echo get_the_time('d/m/Y', $post->ID); ?></p></div>
              <div class="post-info">
                <h2 class="post-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="post-content">
              <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to do it.  You should avoid use of `query_posts` and `get_posts` in most situations, and `WP_Query` is far more appropriate here.

The reason you are getting several copies of each post is because you modify the main query to get posts from that category, then inside the Loop you `get_posts` from that query and display all of them via `foreach`, so you are outputting every post in that category for every post in that category due to the nested loops. `get_posts` is not for use in conjunction with the Loop.

This should do it for you:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php

        $catquery = new WP_Query('category_name=nieuwsitem&posts_per_page=20');
        if ($catquery->have_posts()) :
        while ( $catquery->have_posts() ) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post-item">
                  <div class="thedate"><?php echo get_the_time('d/m/Y', $post->ID); ?></p></div>
                  <div class="post-info">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="post-content">
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. 
        else :
            echo '<h3>No posts found.</h3>';
        endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

$args  array ( 'category_name' => 'nieuwsitem', 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ;

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

**And remove :**

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

endwhile;

I think you query your post with two query so every times you get a post with : 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

You query the posts again with : $myposts = get_posts('');